# PHP regular expressions for time

Tags: php, regex, cakephp

I have time represented like these possibilites:

```
7:15:00 AM
07:15:00 AM

7:15:00 PM
07:15:00 PM
```

How do I adjust the regex below to make the above fit? The rules I need to add is the optional 0 in the front and the optional space AM or space PM.

```
/[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]/
```

Comment: did you think of just using strtotime()

Comment: btw `/[0-2][0-9]` is not valid

Comment: @diEcho why is it not valid ? It just means "a digit between 0 and 2 included followed by a digit between 0 and 9 included", I use such things alot ...

Comment: it will validate `20--29` too where as OP using `AM PM` means string will be  in 12 hours format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use  (`?`) operator  or  `{0,1}`

```
   /[0-2]?[0-9]:[0-5]?[0-9]:[0-5]?[0-9]\s?[AM|PM]/i
```

**Better Approach :** check with [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

### edit:

i think this is better one because i think `[0-2]?[0-9]` is not valid regex

```
   /1[012]|0?[1-9]:[0-5]?[0-9]:[0-5]?[0-9]\s?[AM|PM]/i
```

Comment: That is not the "greedy" operator it is a shortcut for `{0,1}`, means match 0 or 1 time ==> it makes the preceding part optional. If it is used after another quantifier it makes that quantifier **ungreedy**.

Comment: @stema isn't this validate time between `20-29` too where as OP using `AM|PM` means string will be in 12 hours format

Comment: sorry I misunderstood you. You are right, it is not valid as it does not meet the OP's requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use PHP's [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function instead to do all your work?

*The function expects to be given a string containing an English date format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC), relative to the timestamp given in now, or the current time if now is not supplied.*

Comment: @MadCoder It won't be any less accurate than regex'ing the data out and saving it though. Set your timezone and you should be miles ahead - with the added benefit that if the input changes slightly, it won't throw the regex into a fit.

Comment: You're right.  It only becomes an issue if you try to use the "date portion" of the timestamp which would be dumb anyway.  A simple date("h:i:s A",strtotime($mydate)) should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
/[0-1]{0,1}[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] (AM|PM)/
```